# Flight Plan - Rights of use and distribution to third parties

Tags: flight-plans

Currently we have in mind a meteorological project, specially designed for pilots and aviation professionals, for which, the only thing that we currently lack is to have the flight plans. It seems to be (as Eurocontrol tells us) that flight plan information is only distributed to airlines and air traffic control companies, not to third parties. Therefore, the only thing that remains is for the pilot to provide us with the flight plan.

What use rights does a flight plan have? Is there a problem in which the pilot shares this information with third parties?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! IMO, usage rights are a minor issue compared to what you can offer and how it would integrate into existing flight planning tools. In other words, market research and product development. As a Q&A site (see the [tour]) we don't encourage discussions, so I think your idea about talking to a pilot (preferably to a lot of pilots) is a good one. But if you have specific, objective questions that would fit the format of this site then please do ask them.